# Can I bypass/skip the ADFS login screen and use my own custom login screen to access MSCRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, adfs

I am using MSCRM authenticated through ADFS.I have two active directories A and B.I setup a one-way forest trust between A and B so that users in B can access my resources in A.I currently use ADFS for login.my problem is it is not friendly for a user to key in A\username or B\username to login to my webpage.Therefore I wish to build a custom login screen and maybe provide a radio button for the user to choose whether they belong to domain A or domain B.Because i use MSCRM,am I sort of forced to us ADFS?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN provides a series of entries about [ADFS 2.0 Sign-In Pages Customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895356.aspx).

From the linked overview page:

> The Sign-In Pages expose extensibility points that allow a developer
>   to perform the following customizations: Change the accepted and
>   default authentication types.
>
> Customize the theme of the Sign-In Pages and add a company logo image.
>
> Customize the behavior and layout of Sign-In Pages that are seen by
>   the end user, such as the Forms Authentication and Home Realm
>   Discovery pages.
>
> These **customizations can be done by modifying the Web.config** file of
>   the Sign-In Pages Web application **or by modifying specific pages**.

On a side note, as far as I've seen on our customers with IFD environments, you don't need to specify the domain when you sign-in, plain username and password seem to work (I'm not very expert in ADFS, but I understand that it "knows" which domain to authenticate against).